# Keycloak doesn't offer passwordless authentication as the first option during login

Tags: keycloak, webauthn, redhat-sso

I've configured Keycloak authentication for the following behaviour:

- The user inputs its userid
- Keycloak should try to authenticate it with the passwordless flow
- As an alternative the user could switch to password authentication

NOTE: The user already has a registered passwordless device:

[image]

The authentication flow has been configured as follows:

[image]

I access `localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/account` and click on Sign in:

[image]

I input the userid:

[image]

But, instead of being offered to sign up with the security device, I'm asked for the password:

[image]

If I select Try another way and click on Security Key:

[image]

[image]

I am now offered to login with the device:

[image]

Which I can do successfully.

The problem here is that I need the passwordless login to be offered directly, not the password form. Passwordless is actually configured as the first alternative option so why isn't it working as expected?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code of [AuthenticationSelectionResolver](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/18.0.2/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/AuthenticationSelectionResolver.java#L63) this seems to be intended behaviour.
Try to change the order/position of credentials for your user from within the admin console.

[image]

The order of credentials should affect the order in which alternative authenticators will be executed.

Comment: My users are federated from LDAP so I don't have the option to order their credentials. However, I think it would make much more sense to prioritize the order of the authentication from the flow. Thus the same behaviour would apply to all users

Comment: Like @sventorben said. Check this issue: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/12102